# C macros with opening and closing tags?

Tags: c, exception, macros, setjmp

I just started reading [this article](http://www.on-time.com/ddj0011.htm) about exception handling in c with the use of setjmp( jmp_buf ) and longjmp( jmp_buf, int ). So I basically build the linked list that uses the local variables from type xRecord and links it to the list. (Example 2) It works just fine. But in example 3 the steps get summarized into macros (XTRY and XEND). What irritates me most is that the actual switch statement of example 2 just "vanished" in 3.

Example 2:

```
   #define DIVIDE_BY_ZERO -3
   int SomeFunction(int a, int b)
   {
      if (b == 0) // can't divide by 0
         XRaise(DIVIDE_BY_ZERO);
      return a / b;
   }

   void main(void)
   {
      XRecord XData;
      XLinkExceptionRecord(&XData);
      switch (setjmp(XData.Context))
      {
         case 0: // this is the code block
            {
               int Result = SomeFunction(7, 0);
               // continue working with Result
            }
            break;
         case DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
            printf("a division by zero occurred\n");
            break;
         default:
            printf("some other error occurred\n");
            break;
         case XFINALLY:
            printf("cleaning up\n");
      }
      XUnLinkExceptionRecord(&XData);
   }
```

---

Example 3:

```
void main(void)
   {
      XTRY
         case XCODE: // this is the code block
            {
               int Result = SomeFunction(7, 0);
               // continue working with Result
            }
            break;
         case DIVIDE_BY_ZERO: // handler for a
                                 specific exception
            printf("a division by zero occurred\n");
            break;
         default: // default handler
            printf("some other error occurred\n");
            break;
         case XFINALLY: // finally handler
            printf("cleaning up\n");
      XEND
   }
```

My question is, how can I build these "opening and closing" macros?

Comment: Right. So what is your question?

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: uuh, don't do it. Never, ever invent macros that change the textual structure of C. Blocks in C are given by `{}`. There is never a need for such a thing. Just put the `{}` around it.

Comment: The real problem: there is no way to recover from `void main()`. Hiding setjmp/longjmp behind macros will not help anybody; it is even more stupid than `#define BEGIN {`, `#define AND &&` et.al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the two examples, and keep in mind that C macros are simple text substitutions, what the macros should be is evident:

```
#define XTRY  XRecord XData; \
              XLinkExceptionRecord(&XData); \
              switch (setjmp(XData.Context)) \
              {

#define XEND  } \
              XUnLinkExceptionRecord(&XData);
```

Note the use of `\` to allow the macro to span more than one line.

You may also want to have the macros open and close a new scope (by adding `{` and `}`), so that using the macros multiple in succession doesn't give an error due to multiple definitions of the variable `XData`. You can also use the [`do / while(0)` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros) to allow these macros to be placed directly inside `if`, `for`, etc. without issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide the `{}` this only causes trouble. With a C99 compliant compiler, you can hide local variables  and some code that is executed before and after the block:

```
#define MY_BLOCK                                          \
for (int once = 0; once < 1; ++once)                      \
  for (XRecord XData = { 0 }; once < 1; ++once)           \
    for (XLinkExceptionRecord(&XData); (XUnLinkExceptionRecord(&XData), (once < 1)); ++once) \
       switch (setjmp(XData.Context))
```

Benefit would be that you only need one macro instead of two, and the `{}` would clearly indicate the scope of the construct, even for your favorite editor.

Comment: I saw that and deleted my comment right before you posted yours. But this still seems overly obfuscated.

Comment: not more obfuscated than the `XTRY` / `XEND` idea from the start.

Comment: True, I suppose. Not needing the end macro *is* a nice touch.